# How to capture print statements inside pytest hooks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am new to pytest frame work and trying to understand pytest hooks. I have placed some print statements in pytest hooks but not sure about how i can print the statement on console.
Here is the example that i tried

```
# content of conftest.py
import pytest
import sys

def pytest_load_initial_conftests(args):
  print ("Hello")
  if 'xdist' in sys.modules:  # pytest-xdist plugin
    import multiprocessing

    num = max(multiprocessing.cpu_count() / 2, 1)
    args[:] = ["-n", str(num)] + args
    print ("args: ", args)
```

```
# content of the test_sample.py
def test_answer():
  # assert 0
  print ("test function")
  pass
```

I have tried using `pytest test_sample.py -s`,  `pytest --capture=sys/fd/no`. I could only obtain print statement on console from the test_answer function  but not from the pytest hook.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the documentation of the [`pytest_load_initial_conftests`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_load_initial_conftests) hook,

> Note:
>
> This hook will not be called for `conftest.py` files, only for setuptools plugins.

So placing it into `conftest.py` has no effect. You need to invoke the hook via `pytest` plugin system. Either move the hook impl to a separate package, as advised in the docs:

```
# myplugin.py

def pytest_load_initial_conftests(args):
    ...

# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='myplugin',
    py_modules=['myplugin'],
    entry_points={'pytest11': ['myplugin = myplugin']}
)
```

and install it as usual via `pip install`/`python setup.py install`.

Or keep `myplugin.py` with the rest of the code and pass the custom plugin via `-p` arg:

```
$ pytest -p myplugin
```

You may need to update `PYTHONPATH` for `myplugin.py` to become importable. The custom plugin arg may be moved to `pytest.ini` to ease the invocation:

```
[pytest]
addopts = -p myplugin
```